# For an electric field passing through a charged sheet, what would be the boundary conditions if E(above) and E(below) were both pointing downwards?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, boundary-conditions

[image]

Consider the diagram given in Griffith's figure 2.36. we can see that boundary condition is E(above) - E(below) = $\sigma/ \epsilon_0$. According to Griffith's the direction of n is always from "below to above". My question is what would've been the boundary conditions if E(above) and E(below) pointed downwards?